# What are all the bootstrap.html items shown when running a WinJS app?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, windows-8, winjs

I am having difficulty with a memory leak in an adopted WinJS Windows 8 app. When debugging, I am noticing under **MSAppHost** there are a LOT of items under **default.html** named **bootstrap.html**?bubblePointerEvents=1 ... dozens of them. Does anyone know the purpose of these? It appears to be an internal WinJS runtime thing, but I figure thats where my memory leak may be.

Ideas?

Image attached, of course.
[image: dozens of bootstrap items with associated scripts]

Comment: These bootstrap.html files are not twitter bootstrap - they are the MS advertising ad control

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new Visual Studio 2012 JavaScript memory leak analysis tools.

A good tutorial is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj819178.aspx).

Comment: That helped, but it appears Microsoft advertising is the leak. Is there a way to quickly release all event handlers from an object? Thanks, and Happy New Year!

Comment: Destroy the object holding the handlers -- for a DOM element, this means detaching the element from the DOM, and anything else that refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you inherited code from elsewhere, and this code uses [Twitter Bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter_Bootstrap).

When running the app, do you see any errors in the JavaScript Console in Visual Studio?

Comment: The only error I see is: APPHOST9623: The app couldn’t resolve ms-appx://...my app's name.../undefined because of this error: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.

No errors appear to be thrown, however. Is there a hint to stop on ALL errors with WinJS apps?